# Is there any macro or environment to represent target\classes folder

Tags: java, maven

Using maven, all the classes and resources are copied to target\classes folder.

Is there a way to represent target\classes folder using environment variable from code?

Or can I copy resources to root folder?

Comment: Just load the resources using the classloader.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy resources to the `resources` folder under `src/main` or `src/test` as appropriate. You may need to create the directory.